# Execute a stored procedure using SQL Server 2008 in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to execute a stored procedure using a SSIS package.

The output that generates from this stored procedure will also a script, so I want to execute that script output too. Can I schedule this SSIS package using SQL Server Agent?

Comment: Your previous iteration of this question was closed as not describing the specific problem. This iteration is a close match to that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911323/how-to-create-stored-procedure-and-execute-using-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @billinkc Your link goes to a 404

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a stored procedure in an Execute SQL Task in SSIS and send the output to a variable. You can then read the content of that variable in a second Execute SQL Task.

And yes, you can schedule the package to execute via a SQL Server Agent job. [See this link for details](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/).

Cheers -

Comment: @simon.... thnx, Can you pls help me out more in how can I run my stored procedure by SSIS step by step.

Comment: What do you mean by step by step? An SSIS package cannot be run in bits; you run the whole thing or none of it. Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: I have a stored procedure and I want to execute it using SSIS,so how can I do.?

Comment: Just add a SQL Task to the SSIS package and set the sql to be        exec sp_name

Comment: But while parsing it is giving error like- deferred could not complete

Comment: Can you get more details on the error? And what SQL is it running?